# Saving Spinner value to SharedPreferences then setting the Spinner to that saved String

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, spinner

I have a Spinner named `strength` that I need to grab its value and save it to SharedPreferences. Then when the user starts the same activity (`SaAStrength`) again, the Spinner named `strength` needs to be set to what they already selected.

The code I have currently doesn't set the spinner to the saved string in Prefs.

I'm quite lost as to how to approach this.

```
package com.mikitz.rogsimple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SaAStrength extends Activity {

Spinner strength, melee, h2h, parry; 

SharedPreferences pref;

String getstrength, getmelee, geth2h, getparry; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.saa_strength);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Character1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    strength = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.strength);

    strength = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.strength);
    Integer[] items1 = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items1);
    strength.setAdapter(adapter1);

    melee = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.melee);
    Integer[] items2 = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items2);
    melee.setAdapter(adapter2);

    h2h = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.h2h);
    Integer[] items3 = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items3);
    h2h.setAdapter(adapter3);

    parry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.parry);
    Integer[] items4 = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items4);
    parry.setAdapter(adapter4);

    getstrength = pref.getString("strength", "");
    strength.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)strength.getAdapter()).getPosition(getstrength));
}

public void onBackPress()
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();

    editor.putString("strength", strength.getSelectedItem().toString());

    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(this, "GREAT SUCCESS!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, NewSkillsAndAttributes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: you have two `strength = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.strength);`

Comment: look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/3326331)

Comment: hey is this `onBackPress()` method being alled from  `@Override
public void onBackPressed() { ..}` ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal hahaha that fixed the saving to Prefs issue. But the code I have up there doesn't set the spinner to the saved string.

Comment: which comment fixed the saving issue?

Comment: try `getstrength = pref.getString("strength", null);` and then `if(getstrength !=null){..}` check if it is null

Comment: Check what does this give? : `Toast.makeText(this, " index : "+((ArrayAdapter)strength.getAdapter()).getPosition(getstrength), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: It can't be null as the Spinner defaults to 1

Comment: @Dhruti is said `index: -1` It says that no matter what value I put in the spinner

Comment: You checked after `getstrength = pref.getString("strength", "");` line, right?

Comment: And check this too: `Toast.makeText(this, " getStrength: "+getStrength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: @Dhruti yeah, I did.

Comment: getting correct string in `getStrength`?

Comment: The string is `getstrength` not `getStrength`. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Mikitz06 check your String getstrength's value. I made a typo. check toast of `Toast.makeText(this, " getstrength: "+getstrength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` . Is it proper? the string shows what you selected in spinner?

Comment: I don't think it's proper as the index value is always -1 no matter the value I select in the spinner